# "How long a gap do I need between treatments." OR "How long do I need between treatments."

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, idiomatic-language, questions

This sentence is from a web site about laser treatments.

**"How long a gap do I need between laser hair removal treatments?"**

**"How long"** refers to time anyway.

So, why do we need to say **"how long a gap...."**. I mean would it be also correct if we said **"How long do I need between ....."?**

Comment: Yes, it would be fine.

Comment: "an interval" would be an alternative to gap. "What interval should I leave....?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inference of your statement is that a gap *should* be left between treatments, presumably for a good reason, ie if you have the treatments too close together it can cause a problem. The focus of the question is on that gap being of adequate length, and if you don't mention the gap it may not make sense. If you just say "*how long do I need between treatments?*" it raises the question "*need for what?*" Does something specific have to be done between treatments? If it is just a waiting period, then that needs to be referenced.

If your reason for wanting to omit these words is to shorten the sentence, one alternative would be:

> How long *should I wait* between laser hair removal treatments?

Comment: you are right this is opinion based, I think "how long do i need between" is perfectly fine, what else could they be talking about except time?

Comment: Isn't 'begs the question' only an acceptable substitute for 'raises the question in vernacular English, because of the former's formal meaning 'to attempts to support a claim with a premise that itself restates or presupposes the claim'?

Comment: @WendyG Of course they are talking about time, but time for what? If there *needs* to be a gap between treatment then that needs to be stated.

Comment: The meaning seems clear (at least to me) whether or not you include "a gap", but if you particularly want to emphasise that a gap is required, then explicitly mentioning a gap does that. That said, this is a very trivial question and it doesn't matter much. (In other cases obsessing over the fewest possible words is undesirable and redundancy is useful; in this case there is less value. But this isn't really about English language.)